# Why can't I use VecDeque::push_back inside of a Mutex?

Tags: rust, mutex

I'm writing a program that will concurrently call an API and fill a `VecDeque` with integers from the response JSON. Since these will be running concurrently, I wrapped the `VecDeque` in a `Mutex`. When I test the code and try to push an integer into the `VecDeque`, I get an error.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut tank = Mutex::new(VecDeque::new());
    // let mut tank = VecDeque::with_capacity(10);

    tank.push_back(2);
    tank.push_back(3);

    println!("{:?}", tank);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
 tank.push_back(2);
      ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::sync::Mutex<VecDeque<_>>
```

Do I need to create the `VecDeque` inside a struct instead?

Comment: You need to `lock()` the mutex. But using std's mutex with tokio is a bad idea.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Not necessarily. As [tokio documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.14.0/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use) explicitly states, "Contrary to popular belief, it is ok and often preferred to use the ordinary `Mutex` from the standard library in asynchronous code." A case like the OP's where the only thing done while the mutex is locked is a `VecDeque::push_back()` is a perfect example of where using a "blocking" mutex would be the right thing to do. You need to use async mutexes if you plan to keep the mutex locked across `.await` points.

Comment: With the above in mind, I'd like to add that using [`parking_lot`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot) might be a better idea than using `std::sync::Mutex`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion, I needed to lock before changing the `VecDeque`. It works now:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut tank = Mutex::new(VecDeque::new());

    let mut tank = tank.lock().unwrap().push_back(2);
    let mut tank = tank.lock().unwrap().push_back(3);

    println!("{:?}", tank);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Note that the simpler `tank.lock().unwrap().push_back(2)` works as well, and doesn't require a new scope and local vairable. Also, if you need to push two things, you can reuse the same locked variable, which will avoid unnecessary locking/unlocking of the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The reason I structured it this way is because I'm building a larger script that will make an async call to an API, so the lock will drop after each push_back.